# Rails counting Sql during rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I display the query count in rendering the view.

I would like to show the text message like

```
Processed with 8 queries.
```

For PHP version is

```
function query($query)
{
    //We increase the queries counter by 1
    global $nb_queries,$timer_queries;
    $nb_queries++;
    //Execute the query and time the execution time
    $beginning = timer();
    //Execute the query and save the result in a variable
    $req_return = mysql_query($query);
    //We add the query duration to the total
    $timer_queries += round(timer()-$beginning,6);
    return $req_return;
}
```

How can I do similar in rails

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: For development is SQLite, will be use MySQL in production

Comment: Did you consider using [rails-footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes) or [rails_panel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel) if you only want this in development?

Comment: hopefully displaying on the footer for easy monitoring or debugging

Answer (score 0):

Just found a gem resolve my question.

Query Diet https://github.com/makandra/query_diet